# На чем была написана Java?

Tags: java, jvm

Собственно стало интересно и гугл не смог дать мне ответа.
Везде пишут что разрабатывался с оглядкой на C++, но вот на чем собственно написан(или с помощью чего) нигде не оговаривается. Так же интересно на чем пишут JVM для новых ОС или устройств. Кто знает расскажите, интересно ведь.

Comment: Странно, что никто не упомянул то, что помимо кода на c и c++ у jvm есть ещё ассемблерные вставки

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Действительно интересный вопрос, поискал нашел ответ, который меня в принципе удовлетворил: [What is java written in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410320/what-is-java-written-in)

Comment: Да почти все языки так или иначе написано на С++ и(или) на С ^^

Comment: Только не "языки", а их интерпретаторы, компиляторы и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

Естественно, интерпретаторы, виртуальные машины, компиляторы, в том числе JIT, пишутся на С или С++ (во всяком случае, их ядра) как на языках, дающих наибольшую скорость выполнения программ.

Comment: Разве Java интерпретатор? Там JIT компиляция вроде.

Comment: Это сильно зависит от используемого `JDK`. В ответе на `stackoverflow` есть примеры `JDK`, написанных на `Java`.

Comment: Это скорее экзотика. Теоретически можно написать на любом языке, средства которого это позволяют. Наиболее распространенный вариант - С/С++ по указанным мною причинам.

Answer (score 0):

или на С, или на С++ (не знаю точно, м. б. просто на С, без надстроек)