# Как работает JVM написанная на Java?

Tags: java, jvm

Объясните, недалекому.
Для запуска Java приложений требуется JVM.
Есть JVM, написанная на Java.
Получается, что для запуска JVM, нужна JVM? =)

Comment: Про какую именно JVM написанную на Java вы говорите?

Comment: https://github.com/beehive-lab/Maxine-VM

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/54582/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-java и тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410320/what-is-java-written-in вы можете найти ответы на эти вопросы.

Comment: Я так понимаю, компилируют на JVM, написанной на C, и потом используют. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Слышали выражение: «eat your own dog food»?

Answer (score 5):

Если вы посмотрите языки используемые в репозитории [Maxine-VM](https://github.com/beehive-lab/Maxine-VM), то увидите, что 1.6% кода - это код на C:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если загляните в документацию, то сможете найти такой текст:

> The Maxine VM is written almost entirely in Java, **with a small part,**
>   **called the substrate, written in C. The substrate implements the**
>   **native launcher for the Maxine VM.** It encapsulates in a
>   platform-independent API the native services from the Operating System
>   (OS), e.g., virtual memory operation, native thread support, and
>   signal handling. The substrate also includes native services to
>   support JNI and JVMTI.

То есть дополнительная виртуальная машина для запуска этой JVM не нужна. Она уже содержит необходимый минимум для запуска, написанный на C. А после запуска станет виртуальной машиной для самой себя.